# CLISP Terminal error: Invalid byte sequence

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

i have a problem while loading my source file inside terminal using clisp.
if i execute the following command to load the file:

```
(load #p "filename.lisp")
```

it gives me the following error:

```
SYSTEM::LINE-COMMENT-READER: Invalid byte sequence #xE0 #xA0 #x20 in
CHARSET:UTF-8 conversion
```

can someone please tell me what i need to do in order to load the file?
thank you.

Comment: That looks like there's an error in the file you're loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is encoded with [ISO-8859-1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_8859-1):

```
$ file filename.lisp 
filename.lisp: ISO-8859 text, with no line terminators
```

Based on CLISP's documentation about [encodings](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html):

```
(load #P"filename.lisp" :external-format 'charset:iso-8859-1)
```