# Charsets in Common Lisp

Tags: xml, windows, xml-parsing, common-lisp, clisp

I've been working on a common lisp program that parses through two XML files and combines them in a custom way to make a third XML. Unfortunately, lisp uses the CP1252 charset while my XML files use UTF-8 and contain some Japanese characters that can't be used in CP1252.

I've been trying to make clisp use the UTF-8 by adding

```
:external-format 'charset:UTF-8
```

To both the load (as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630483/clisp-terminal-error-invalid-byte-sequence)) and `read-line` (because why not) functions, but clisp still throws up this error:

> READ-LINE: Invalid byte #x81 in CHARSET:CP1252 conversion

Is there a way to do what I want with the code I have? I'm still fairly new to lisp.

Full Read Function Code:

```
(defun readXML (stream libSize)
    (defparameter lib nil)
    (defparameter x 1)
    (loop
        (defparameter lib (cons (read-line stream :external-format 'charset:UTF-8) lib))
        (defparameter x (+ x 1))
        (when (> x libSize) (return lib))))
```

Comment: `read-line` does _not_ accept `:external-format`. Also, I think you are confusing `load` and `open`. Finally, please include your complete code.

Comment: Adding external format to read-line was just a random thing I tried. Regarding the load- I have been launching clisp from the windows command prompt and using (load "filename.lisp" :external format 'charset:UTF-8).

Comment: Does your `"filename.txt"` contain lisp forms? If yes, why did you give it `"txt"` file type instead of the more common `"lisp"` or `"l"` or `"cl"`? If not, why are you using [`load`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_load.htm) on it?

Comment: My mistake in typing the comment up - it is a .lisp not a .txt.

Comment: "lisp uses the CP1253 charset"? Lisp is not a language, it is a family of languages any one of which might have multiple implementations, each of which may support different charsets in different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Mistakes

### [`read-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm)

This function does *not* accept the [`:external-format`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/open.html#extfmt) argument.

It does accept several optional parameters, but they have nothing to do
with encodings.

### [`defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm)

This is a "top-level" operator, it creates a global [dynamic variable](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#dynamic_variable).
*Never* use it inside a function.
Use [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) there instead - it [*binds* variables lexically](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lexical_variable).
`loop` (see below) also binds the variables.

## Correct code

```
(defun read-lines (file-name max-lines)
  "Open the file and read it line-by-line, at most `max-lines'."
  (with-open-file (stream file-name :external-format charset:utf-8)
    (loop :for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
      :for line-number :upfrom 0
      :while (and line (< line-number max-lines))
      :collect line)))
```

Or, slightly simpler (as suggested by @jkiiski):

```
(defun read-lines (file-name max-lines)
  "Open the file and read it line-by-line, at most `max-lines'."
  (with-open-file (stream file-name :external-format charset:utf-8)
    (loop :for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
      :repeat max-lines
      :while line
      :collect line)))
```

### Explanations

- [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) opens the
  file, binds `stream` to the result and makes sure that the stream is
  closed on exit.
- [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) is a very advanced
  iteration facility. It binds `line` to each successive line, counts
  them using `line-number`, and collects lines into the return value:

  - [`for`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abad.htm)
  - [`upfrom`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abaa.htm)
  - [`while` and `repeat`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abaa.htm)
  - [`collect`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm)

PS. Please follow all links in the answer. 
They explain each operator in detail.

Comment: `:REPEAT MAX-LINES` would be a bit simpler since `LINE-NUMBER` isn't used for anything else.